# How to Handle Large Amount of Data in Mysql or Infobright Databases...?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have two tables :
Table A(with 1 billions records)
Table B(with 20 million records)

We need to fetch or select the data with the join of between these tables.

Which type of optimization mysql required for getting the proper result.?

Kindly suggest the possible or appropirate solutions.

Proper Indexing (**Done**)

Answer (score 0):

As INfobright is columunar database with no indexing.

Querying a large table (with very few WHERE clauses) AND adding many joins can still be slow. Try putting the large table in its own sub query:  select * from (select date, .. from largetable group by...) inner join othertable